# APScheduler pytz-deprecation-shim not found when building an exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, apscheduler, pytz

When running my exe that I built with pyinstaller I get an error every time when using APScheduler in the program.

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pytz-deprecation-shim' distribution was not found and is required by tzlocal
```

I already got a similar problem before with the distributions: pytz, tzlocal and six that APScheduler seems to use, but I could fix that by creating a `hook-pytz.py` `hook-tzlocal.py` `hook-six.py` file which each contains the following code with the corresponding distribution:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata, collect_data_files

datas = copy_metadata('pytz')
datas += collect_data_files('pytz')
```

When building the app with pyinstaller I then call `--additional-hooks-dir=`
However, now the same procedure isn't working for the pytz-deprecation-shim, as I always receive the same error. How can I fix the problem? I already tried upgrading all those packages to the newest version but they seem to be up to date.

versions:
pytz 2021.3,
pytz-deprecation-shim 0.1.0.post0,
tzlocal 4.1,
six 1.16.0,
APScheduler 3.8.1

Comment: APScheduler version is 3.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered this problem today.

My solution is to use APScheduler 3.6.3.

This is my `hook-apscheduler.py`

```
datas = copy_metadata('apscheduler', recursive=True)
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('apscheduler')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that worked for me. However, how could you handle the tzdata problem. Without pasting the code --collect-all tzdata into my pyinstaller command, the program again will crash. If I do it everything works fine, but then the .exe obviously is always using the timezone that my device has but not one of all the other users if I distribute it. Is there any solution to that?

Comment: First, the command - collect-all tzdata has the same effect as creating a hook-tzdata.py. Second, it is recommended to use the --additional-hooks-dir command to specify multiple packages in the folder, similar to hook-tzdata.py, because this can specify multiple packages, while, -- collect all can specify only one package. Third, how to specify the time zone, you can do this:

Comment: from tzlocal import get_localzone

Comment: local_tz = get_localzone()

Comment: scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone=local_tz)